# Proving a Certain Property of Monoidal Categories

Tags: category-theory

Hi category theory stack exchange,

Is it true that the expression $(f;g)\otimes h=(f\otimes h);(g \otimes I)$ holds? It feels like it "should" from what I know about monoidal categories, but I am not sure how to assert it.

Here's a diagram to show what I mean:
[[image: <span class=]$(f;g)\otimes h=(f\otimes h);(g \otimes I)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLcid.png)

I always felt like this was one of the "fundamental" properties of monoidal categories, the thing that makes them tick. But few of the monoidal category axioms actually address how the morphism $\times$ morphism $\rightarrow$ morphism aspect of the generating bifunctor behaves. There are lots of [regularity criteria for the objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category), but I have not found much for the morphisms. If anyone can clarify, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please disregard the comment above, and welcome to MSE. This is a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to check such questions is by drawing string diagrams, which make the answer absolutely immediate (the answer is "yes.") A good introduction to string diagrams is [here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3347)

That said, in this case, let $C$ be our monoidal category and let $f:x\to y,g:y\to z,h:u\to v.$ Then $(f;g)\otimes (h;\mathrm{id})$ is $\otimes((f,h);(g,\mathrm{id})),$ where now we write $\otimes$ explicitly as a functor $C\times C\to C.$ Then merely by functoriality, we conclude that $(f;g)\otimes (h;\mathrm{id})=\otimes((f,h);(g,\mathrm{id}))=\otimes((f;g,h))=(f;g)\otimes h,$ as we wanted to show.

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, section 3.1 in the book you linked covered my question. Thanks for the help! (It's the bifunctor property)